# Mimicking srcset HTML 5 attribute in PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, srcset

I have an array with URLs for download:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/1.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/1.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/1.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/1.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/2.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/2.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/2.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/2.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/100.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/100.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/100.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/100.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/200.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/200.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/200.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/200.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/300.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/300.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/300.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/300.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png',
    'http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png',
    'http://ads.480x90.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png',
    'http://ads.768x120.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png',
    'http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png');
```

The width of each of the images is found before the `x`.

Now the task is to find those URLs that match a given arbitrary screen resolution the best. So, for instance if the screen resolution is 1920x1080, the array would be shortened to only contain URLs that are 900 pixels wide (ie. `http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png`, `http://ads.900x150.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png` etc.)

If the screen resolution is 320x480 then the array would only contain `http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/12.png`, `http://ads.320x60.us.dizplayzone.com/55.png` etc.)

What I want to mimic is basically the same behaviour as the srcset attribute for image tags in HTML5 using either PHP or Java.

After the array has been shortened the URLs still in the array can then be downloaded.

Can this be done?

Comment: "PHP or Java" is an unusual pair of languages to be interchangeable. Are you sure you don't mean Java***Script*** ?

Comment: Yes. The reason why I mentioned both is that I am currently doing a backend for a mobile app (in PHP) but later I will be doing the mobile app itself (in JAVA) and I just wanted to try to write the code in PHP first and then translate into Java later...